# mysqljs проблема с кодировкой

Tags: mysql, node.js, utf-8

При выводе в консоль строки из бд, содержащей "Привет", выводится абракадабра.

```
...
var mysql= require('mysql');
var connectionmysql = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});
connectionmysql.connect();
connectionmysql.query('SELECT * FROM dopuslugi WHERE id=?',[msg.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
  console.log(rows[0].name);
});
```

Добавление в mysql.createConnection charset:'utf8' не помогает, добавление

```
connectionmysql.query("SET NAMES utf8");
connectionmysql.query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
connectionmysql.query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

не помогает. Через PHP эта строка выводится без искажений.

Comment: Надо попытаться расшифровать аброкадабру например через Лебедевский "Автоматический декодер почты", ну или любой другой восстановитель кодировки, и от этого уже искать проблему, может просто ответ приходит в BASE64

Answer (score 0):

В базу данные вставлялись через PHP, а он был некорректно настроен для работы с UTF-8.